# Difference between 打电话给 and 打电话和?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

如果只能活24小时，我会打电话和朋友们说再见。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, segment 21. What is the difference between 打电话给 and 打电话和？I would write it as:

如果只能活24小时，我会打电话给朋友们说再见。

So what is the difference? What is the meaning of 和？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"打电话[**给**]朋友" is a complete sentence. It means "make a phone call [**to**] a friend" (*打电话 is the only verb needed*).

"打电话[**和**]朋友"(make a phone call [**with**] a friend) is an incomplete sentence. You need a second verb 'talk' here --> "打电话和[**和**]朋友通話" = "make a phone call and talk [**with**] a friend"

- talk = 通話/ 交談
- **和**朋友们说再见 = **跟**朋友们说再见